# Why does Outlook show background images when I receive html mail via Outlook but not when I send html Mails via Outlook?

Tags: css, outlook, html-email, vml

I cannot wrap my head around it. I created a html Mail. In order to send it I open the html file in Google Chrome and then I copy paste all into the new email.

**Now there are three Scenarios:**

1. When I copy paste it into Apple Mail, send it via Apple Mail and then open the Mail in Outlook (Latest Version of Outlook for Mac) it works perfectly fine and the background image is shown.
2. When I copy paste it into Outlook to send the Mail the background image isn't shown at all.
3. When I forward the Mail from Scenario (1) the background image gets lost again and is not shown.

How is that possible? Scenario (1) kind of shows that Outlook is able to show the background image and that the Code is correct but why can i not send it using Outlook?

**I tried:**

1. I am using the "Bulletproof background" method from https://backgrounds.cm/
2. I tried using http instead of https in the Linka for the background images but that didnt help
3. In the first  Tag I tried both background and background-image in the inline CSS.
4. Setting a fixed height for the VML.

   ```
   <td background='https://link/bg-img.jpg' bgcolor="#000000" width="600" valign="top" style="background-image:url('https://link/bg-img.jpg'); background:url('https://link/bg-img.jpg'); background-position: top; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
       <!--[if gte mso 9]>
           <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false"
           style="width:600px;">
           <v:fill type="tile" src="https://link/img.jpg" color="#dadada" />
           <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
       <![endif]-->
       <div>
           <table id="header" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="30" width="600"
               style="mso-cellspacing: 0px; mso-padding-alt: 30px 30px 30px 30px">
               <tr id="logos">
                   <td>
                       <img width="130" style="width: 130px"
                           src="https://link/logo_one.png">
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <img width="150" style="width: 150px" align="right"
                           src="https://link/logo_two.png">
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </table>

           <table id="header-texts" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="25" width="600" 
               style="color: white; text-align: center; mso-cellspacing: 0px; 
               mso-padding-alt: 25px 25px 25px 25px">
               <tr id="title">
                   <td>
                       <p><b>SOME HEADER</b></p>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr id="welcome-text" 
                   style="padding: 30px; margin: 0; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);">
                   <td>
                       <p>SOME TEXT.</p>
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
       </div>
       <!--[if gte mso 9]>
           </v:textbox>
           </v:rect>
       <![endif]-->
   </td>
   ```

Comment: You dont have a height on your VML. Place a height and try the code again. If it still doesnt work, try sending a test using `putsmail` or other free email service to do a test send to see how it looks. Apple mail or Outlook have different ways of interpreting HTML when its sent.

Comment: ^As Syfer said, height may help but ultimately sending an email the way you are doing is really advised, especially if you're working with Background images. Outlook is already temperamental with background images and you're using a process that goes beyond what Outlook would normally expect and support.

Comment: I would suggest simplify your design to allow your email to render properly in more email clients, or look at using an email platform such as Mailchimp.

Comment: @Syfer Thanks for the fast reply. I already tried using a height (Forgot to state that, sorry) wich doesn't work either. Outlook just shows the Fallback color. But I realised that it shows the Fallback color that i declared in the inline CSS of the first <td> Tag not the one in the VML.  And i need a dynamic height. Thats why I used style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" wich is supposed to do that.

Comment: @Syfer When i send the html mail via putsmail everything works perfectly fine just like when i send it with Apple Mail. It just doesn't work when I try to send the Mail via Outlook.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein Wich process would you suggest if I want to send a  html mail via Outlook. And unfortunately I cannot simply the design since it has to match with the overall look we use everywhere else (eg Website).

Comment: The way putsmail sends the email is how it should be sent. If you view source of the email sent from Outlook, you will see its different from what you had coded. Apple mail might be sending parts of the email right but not everything. What putsmail (and other similar services) take what you have coded and send it _as is_. My suggestion will be not to use Outlook or Apple mail to send a mass mail.

Comment: @syfer Ok makes sense. Thanks. What would you recommend to send a lot of Mails? Especially if the mails include personalized Invoices wich are generated with excel and word. Sorry if that is way beyond the initial question.

Comment: Try mailchimp and look for more.